# Get all the titles after deserialiaztion json using C# and Json.net

Tags: c#, deserialization, wikipedia-api, json-deserialization

I am using a wikipedia api which contains external links of all places from a wikipedia article. My wikipedia api call is:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gspage=Berlin&gslimit=500&gsprop=type|name|dim|country|region|globe&format=json

I make c# classes for json object using JsonToCsharp as follows:

```
  public class Geosearch
  {
    public int pageid { get; set; }
    public int ns { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public double dist { get; set; }
    public string primary { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public object dim { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
  }

 public class Query
 {
   public List<Geosearch> geosearch { get; set; }
 }  

 public class RootObject
 {
  public string batchcomplete { get; set; }
  public Query query { get; set; }
 }
```

My deserialization code is as follows.With this code I got only one Title. But I want to get all the title from this api. I know I should make a foreach loop, but could not get logic how to implement it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        var GeoResponse = client.DownloadString("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gspage=Berlin&gslimit=500&gsprop=type|name|dim|country|region|globe&format=json");

        RootObject json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(GeoResponse);

        var firstKey = json.query.geosearch.First().title;

        Console.WriteLine(firstKey);

    }
```

Comment: use `JSON.Net` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine -

```
var o = new HttpClient();
var res = new StreamReader(o.GetStreamAsync("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gspage=Berlin&gslimit=500&gsprop=type|name|dim|country|region|globe&format=json").Result).ReadToEnd() ;
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(res).query.geosearch.Select(a => a.title).ToList();
// count == 500
obj.Foreach(a => Console.WriteLine(a));
```

Comment: it shows error for HttpClient Error 2 The type or namespace name 'HttpClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you must add a reference to `System.Net.Http` assembly

Comment: But it shows as output System.Collections.Generic.List'[System.String]. Not the list. I modified my code in this way-var o = new HttpClient();
            var res = new StreamReader(o.GetStreamAsync("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gspage=Berlin&gslimit=500&gsprop=type|name|dim|country|region|globe&format=json").Result).ReadToEnd();
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(res).query.geosearch.Select(a => a.title).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(obj);

Comment: `obj` is a list of `string`.You'll iterate over the collection and print each at a time. I've edited the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104252/discussion-between-harry-luson-and-amit-kumar-ghosh).

Comment: sorry that typing mistake. I just tried but it shows error Error 2 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Foreach' and no extension method 'Foreach' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

I just modified my code and It is working perfectly.

```
 var response = client.GetAsync("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=10000&gspage=Berlin&gslimit=500&gsprop=type|name|dim|country|region|globe&format=json").Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                var responseContent = response.Content;

                string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseString).query.geosearch.Select(a => a.title).ToList();

                foreach (var item in obj)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I did the same, but differently.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: Thanks. But I got an error with you code. So I just tried in different way. Thank you.